# Python code to connect to twitter search API

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and am very confused on how to begin this assignment:

Write Python code to connect to Twitter search API at:

https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json

with at least the following parameters:

q for a search topic of your interest;

count to 100 for 100 records

to retrieve twitter data and assign the data to a variable.

I already created the app to access Twitter's API. Thanks.

Comment: Either learn to use `requests` or search for "Python twitter client"

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. According to Twitter, you *must* register an account to even use basic search features of public tweets and there is no way around it. I followed the guide for the complete setup [here](https://tomelliott.com/php/authenticating-twitter-feed-timeline-oauth/) and can confirm it works

Edit: the article is for php, but changing it to python shouldn’t be very difficult. It has all the methods outlined in the article

Answer (score -1):

Just as a hint, you might want to use [tweepy](https://www.tweepy.org/) for this. They have very good documentation and its much easier than trying to reinvent the wheel.